# Run spring boot application error: eclipse intellij Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

How to fix this error
I have to run it on Tomcat and a similar web server. Eclipse, I tried intellij

I think there are conflicting package versions - stackoverflow says most answers are just conflicts. but which package has a conflict. Or I couldn't understand if the problem was something else.

This is my Application Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

use maven command: clean package spring-boot:run, exception occurs:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ kip ---
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.9/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize (SpringApplication.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init> (SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at edu.iu.kip.Application.main (Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName (ClassUtils.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize (SpringApplication.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init> (SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at edu.iu.kip.Application.main (Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName (ClassUtils.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances (SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize (SpringApplication.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init> (SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at edu.iu.kip.Application.main (Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

this is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu</groupId>
    <artifactId>kip</artifactId>
    <name></name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <organization>
        <name></name>
        <url></url>
    </organization>

    <scm>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

   <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
          <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.9</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev34-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java7</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev77-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        
        <!-- oracle jdbc
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- Datasource pooling -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lazyluke</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-remix</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Rome Atom+RSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- avaje ebean -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.avaje.ebeanorm</groupId>
            <artifactId>avaje-ebeanorm</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.avaje</groupId>
            <artifactId>avaje-agentloader</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.avaje.ebeanorm</groupId>
            <artifactId>avaje-ebeanorm-agent</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Joda Time Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- File Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        

    
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>



        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <!-- <encoding>ISO8859-9</encoding> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</webappDirectory>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>

                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jasper</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>

                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>

                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <!-- <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
                <!-- <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId> -->
                <!-- <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId> -->
                <!-- <version>3.0.4</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                    <terse>true</terse>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <!-- <autoCreate>true</autoCreate> -->
                    <!-- <skip>${test.int.skip}</skip> -->
                    <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.glassfishDirectory}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>${glassfish.user}</user>
                    <adminPassword>${glassfish.adminPassword}</adminPassword>
                    <!-- <passwordFile>${glassfish.home}/domains/${project.artifactId}/master-password</passwordFile> -->
                    <domain>
                        <name>${glassfish.domain.name}</name>
                        <host>${glassfish.domain.host}</host>
                        <adminPort>${glassfish.domain.adminPort}</adminPort>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>redeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- TOMCAT PLUGIN -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${tomcat.admin.url}</url>
                    <server>${tomcat.admin.server.name}</server>
                    <path>/kip</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>buildnumber</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    <format>{0,number}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work 
                    with ITDs -->
                <version>1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ebean enhancer -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.avaje.ebeanorm</groupId>
                <artifactId>avaje-ebeanorm-mavenenhancer</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>main</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <classSource>${project.build.directory}/classes</classSource>
                            <packages>edu.iu.kip.**</packages>
                            <transformArgs>debug=1</transformArgs>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

`GenericApplicationListener` wasn't added until `4.2` you are using `4.1` and is pretty outdated (Back in 2015). Id suggest updating to the latest version of `5.2.7-RELEASE`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.2.7.RELEASE

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I updated to version 4.2. I got the error output below
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/00_IUC/dev/intellij/kip/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom,

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant use the latest spring framework version?

Answer (score 0):

`showBanner` was replaced with `bannerMode` so you need to do something like:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE); //Prints banner to System.out

new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG); //Prints banner to the log file

new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF); //Disables the banner
```